# Error when running Sinatra's production?, test? and development? methods from the code blocks

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am reading a great book "Jump-start Sinatra" and running all the examples from the book. All the code examples ran great until I reached page 67. This code fails with an error message "NoMethodError at /environment":

```
get '/environment' do
  if development?
    "development"
  elsif production?
    "production"
  elsif test?
    "test"
  else
    "Who knows what environment you're in!"
  end
end
```

It seems like the helper methods work only outside of the code blocks, but fail within the code blocks. Am I doing something wrong, or is it an error in the book?

Comment: Can you post your helper methods and the file they are in?

Comment: They come with Sinatra. I did not define them myself.

Comment: See the addition at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these work for me:

/app.rb:

```
...

helpers do
  def development?
    true
  end
end

get "/environment" do
  if development?
    puts "dev"
  else
    puts "not dev"
  end
end
```

Or,

/app.rb

```
...

module MyHelpers
  def development?
    true
  end
end

helpers MyHelpers

get "/environment" do
  if development?
    puts "dev"
  else
    puts "not dev"
  end
end
```

**Response to comment:**

Call it this way:

```
settings.development?
```

See the Environments section here:  http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Environments

And information about the `settings` object here: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

> **Sinatra includes a number of built-in settings that control whether certain features are enabled. Settings are application-level
>   variables** that are modified using one of the set, enable, or disable
>   methods and are available within the request context via the settings
>   object. Applications are free to set custom settings as well as the
>   default, built-in settings provided by the framework.
>
> Using set, enable, and disable In its simplest form, the set method
>   takes a setting name and value and creates an attribute on the
>   application. **Settings can be accessed within requests via the
>   settings object...**

Answer (score 0):

If `development?` fails in a modular app, you can use:

```
Sinatra::Base.environment == :development
```

For classic Sinatra apps, you can use:

```
Sinatra::Application.environment == :development
```

I learned this from the [Sinatra Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sinatrarb/bn0hNLLGSgE).

Also, the [base.rb](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb) defines the methods like this:

```
def development?; environment == :development end
def production?;  environment == :production  end
def test?;        environment == :test        end
```